# New styles not showing up on an HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have a div that opens like this:

```
<div class='gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper' id='gform_wrapper_8' >
```

I added this code to the css file:

```
.gform_wrapper_8
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;

    text-color: black;
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
}

.gform_wrapper_8 h3
{
    font-weight: normal;  <!-- #lighter -->

    text-color: black;
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
}
```

But I don't see any change in the HTML page for that div. Did I do something incorrectly? Or does the css look right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"gform_wrapper_8" is the ID, so in the CSS it should be

```
#gform_wrapper_8
```

not

```
.gform_wrapper_8
```

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, you select a class with the period (`.`) and IDs with the pound sign (`#`).

So change:

```css
.gform_wrapper_8
```

to:

```css
#gform_wrapper_8
```

since .gform_wrapper_8 is your element's ID, not the class. To style it via the class, use `.gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UPSFY/)**

Answer (score 2):

`#` is for **ID**, `.` is for **class**

```
#gform_wrapper_8{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    text-color: black;
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
}

#gform_wrapper_8 h3{
    font-weight: normal;  <!-- #lighter -->
    text-color: black;
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

[CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Class_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

gform_wrapper_8 is an id, so you should use

```
#gform_wrapper_8
```

instead of

```
.gform_wrapper_8
```

(which is only for class)